# How to get data content from appsheet.com

Tags: php, ruby, curl

Has anyone tried to get data content from appsheet.com with php or ruby?

I have a link that displayed our ticket collect, but i want to display my ticket data only for my self in another link/page with php or ruby.

This is the link :

https://www.appsheet.com/start/df73da6c-b758-4d35-b655-86e1d1fce8e0

Comment: did you try file_get_contents?

Comment: yes i did, but its not display data sheet, just loading image to syncing the app.